# wro4j maven plugin and jshint

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, jshint

I have just tried to use the wro4j maven plugin to get my js checked using jshint on build time.
I have configure the options used by jshint, and the console lists them correctly, but in the code evaluation they are ignored.

Here's the content of my wro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isdc.ro/wro wro.xsd">

    <group name="shop">
        <js>/static/js_source/myjs.js</js>
    </group>
</groups>
```

And here's the plugin code:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>                        
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jshint</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>                    
                <targetGroups>shop</targetGroups>
                <minimize>false</minimize>
                <options>browser,jquery,curly,eqnull,evil,forin,noarg</options>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have played around with different options but nothing seems to work.

Ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a <execution><phase>verify</phase> to have it executed by default?

Comment: In case this is a 1.4.0 bug, you could switch to 1.3.8. There are no big changes in regards to jsHint feature from previous release.

Comment: Hey guys, I have tried 1.3.8 and 1.3.6 with the same result. Using <phase>verify</phase> i see no wro4j infos in the console anymore. Using <phase>compile</phase> I get the infos but the errors as well. For example, even though I have eqnull set as an option, I still get a "reason=Use '===' to compare with '0'."
Can it be a "local problem"? But why would I see the correct options in the console and then they don't get applied?

Comment: I will investigate this and will let you know.

Comment: I think you are expecting to use a newer version of jshint. The wro4j-maven-plugin uses the jshint commited on 2011-06-14 05:23:07.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem... with no success. Are you sure the problem is not in the jsHint? I'm using the following script: 
var j = 1;var i = j == 0 ? j + 1 : j - 1;
and it seems that eqnull has no effect on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex. Does the jshint version which the plugin uses not support some of the options I have chosen? And what exactly do you mean with "problem is not in the jsHint"?

Comment: Can you provide me the exact js example and the options you are using? I will try to reproduce and will find out the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I am using exactly the options you can see above. It's 4000 lines of js i'm evaluating, so I don't think you want all of that... :)

Comment: No, but the simplest example to prove the problem would be enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alex, I'm sorry, I actually misinterpreted both types of errors. eqnull only deals with "== null" and not "== 0" (which is what has thrown the error, and which is different of course). And forin actually -enforces- the use of hasOwnProperty, while I thought it would allow to leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is relavent but I was just attempting to do a very similar thing and having very similar problems (my option choices were being ignored)

I have found that running:

```
wro4j:jshint
```

does **not** seem to apply the supplied options, however, it **applies the options** when run as part of the verify phase:

```
mvn verify
```

This at least, was the reason why I was not seeing my options applied and how I got it to work.

By the sounds of things you tried something similar and had no joy, however, I am posting this answer as I believe others may run in to the same problem I did and come upon this page for the same reasons.